# how to use custom calculation based on two dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as below,

df1

```
index   X1  X2  X3  X4
0   6   10  6   7
1   8   9   11  13
2   12  13  15  11
3   8   11  7   6
4   11  7   6   6
5   13  14  11  10
```

df2

```
index   Y
0   20
1   14
2   17
3   14
4   15
5   20
```

I want to get 3rd dataframe such that new X(i) = Y - (Y/X(i))

```
index   X1  X2  X3  X4
0   16.67   18.00   16.67   17.14
1   12.25   12.44   12.73   12.92
2   15.58   15.69   15.87   15.45
3   12.25   12.73   12.00   11.67
4   13.64   12.86   12.50   12.50
5   18.46   18.57   18.18   18.00
```

Please note, it shall match the index number of df1 and df2 while calculating.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format your code correctly, it's not easy to understand the shape of your data.  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: df3[X1]  = df2[y] -(df2[Y]/df1[X1] . How to do it for all the rows using a loop and matching index of both the dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy for vectorized solution i.e

```
df[df.columns] = (df2.values - df2.values/df.values)

           X1         X2         X3         X4
index                                            
0      16.666667  18.000000  16.666667  17.142857
1      12.250000  12.444444  12.727273  12.923077
2      15.583333  15.692308  15.866667  15.454545
3      12.250000  12.727273  12.000000  11.666667
4      13.636364  12.857143  12.500000  12.500000
5      18.461538  18.571429  18.181818  18.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on `pandas`

```
-(1/df1.div(df2.Y,0)).sub(df2.Y,0)
Out[634]: 
              X1         X2         X3         X4
index                                            
0      16.666667  18.000000  16.666667  17.142857
1      12.250000  12.444444  12.727273  12.923077
2      15.583333  15.692308  15.866667  15.454545
3      12.250000  12.727273  12.000000  11.666667
4      13.636364  12.857143  12.500000  12.500000
5      18.461538  18.571429  18.181818  18.000000
```

Comment: There went my next option